# Run file to execute different file Python?

Tags: python, http, url, download, pycharm

I`m trying to download a book link from a different file but when I executed... the file at the beginning runs well but it crash

```
downloading:  http://31.42.184.140/main/94000/e5772a162f57b7c2b22c7ec8f6883002/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%A2.%D0%9C.%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D1%80.%20-%20%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%28%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%29.djvu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/he/Desktop/New folder (4)/6.py", line 23, in <module>
    exec(l)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/he/Desktop/New folder (4)/6.py", line 9, in download_url
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%A2.%D0%9C.%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D1%80.%20-%20%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%28%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%29.djvu'
```

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def download_url(url):
    print("downloading: ", url)
    file_name_start_pos = url.rfind("/") + 1
    file_name = url[file_name_start_pos:]
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            for data in r:
                f.write(data)
def n(f):
    s = []
    for l in range(1):
        l = f.readline()
        if l:
            s.append(l)
    return s
b = open('1.txt')
c = n(b)
while len(c) > 0:
    for l in c:
        exec(l)
    c = n(b)
b.close()
```

File link:

```
download_url("http://31.42.184.140/main/94000/e5772a162f57b7c2b22c7ec8f6883002/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%A2.%D0%9C.%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D1%80.%20-%20%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%28%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%29.djvu")
```

Comment: Try to put `download_url(r'link here')`

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 1):

You have link with some chars converted to `percent` values - to create url safe for internet - but this is not correct string for filename because system may not use `%` in filenames.

But you can convert it back using `urllib.parser.unquote()`

```
import urllib.parse

name = urllib.parse.unquote("%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%A2.%D0%9C.%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4 %D1%80.%20-%20%D0%93%D0%B
8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0 %2C%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%
8B%20 %D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4 %D1%8B%20%28%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D
0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F %20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82 %D0%B5
%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%29.djvu")

print(name)
```

Result:

```
'Башта Т.М., и д р. - Гидравлика , гидромашины  и гидропривод ы (Учебник для  машиностроит ельных вузов).djvu'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your file name.

You cannot use `%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%A2.%D0%9C.%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4 %D1%80.%20-%20%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0 %2C%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20 %D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4 %D1%8B%20%28%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F %20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82 %D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%29.djvu` As file name

I guess you want to use `e5772a162f57b7c2b22c7ec8f6883002` as the file name, if not, you can choose another name.

If it's not you revising.

I have modified your code, I have successfully downloaded the file of your URL, and can view it without problems.

```py
import requests

url = 'http://31.42.184.140/main/94000/e5772a162f57b7c2b22c7ec8f6883002/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%A2.%D0%9C.%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D1%80.%20-%20%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%28%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%29.djvu'


def download_url(url):
    print("downloading: ", url)
    file_name = f"{url.split('/')[5]}.{url.split('.')[-1]}"
    print(url.split('/')[5])
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)


download_url(url=url)
```

Comment: Thank You dudulu ! !... how instead writing + '.djvu', it can automaticly change to pdf,html,chm,mht,rt depending of the link?

Comment: `file_name = url.split('/')[5] + url.split('.')[-1]`

Comment: Thank You dudulu !!!... I debug it and for me the best way is file_name = url.split('/')[5] + ('.') + url.split('.')[-1]                       ..... THANK YOU BETTY MUCH ! ! !

Comment: ok, I forgot to ask for + `'.'` as long as you can find out.

Comment: No problem. I enjoyed helping you.